# How to create middle ware for checking JWT token on each page (React + Redux)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt

I need to check JWT on each route. So on each page, I will know the status on the JWT token.
I think I can create some kind of middleware but I don't know how to do this with best practices

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Why do you need to check the token? Isn't it enough to send the token with your HTTP requests to the backend?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes. I just need to send a request to a server. So on each page, i will know if JWT is valid

Comment: But why? Server requests are expensive. Just use the key to make a request when you actually need data from the server.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i know that this is expensive but this is requirements. I just need to check user status on each page

Comment: What do you mean by "I just need to check user status"? What exactly do you need to check?